# Updating UI while calling webservice using sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: user-interface, nsurlconnection, synchronized

In my application I am using synchronous request for call webservice. And before each call I want to update my UILabel to show the progress. like:

```
lblTest.text=@"Downloading data XYZ";
NSData *dati = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:richiesta returningResponse:&response error:&error];

lblTest.text=@"Downloading data ABC";
NSData *dati = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:richiesta returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

but label text is not getting changed.

anyone having any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot about this issue , I got a solution.

just need to initiate thread like:

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadData) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

and update label text as:

```
 [lblTest performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:strMessage waitUntilDone:YES];
```

And this resolved my issue.